# Select multiple ListView item without pressing CTRL (Shortcut key)

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to use a ListView in my application, which has to run on a Windows tablet. The problem is that, to select multiple item on a ListView, the user has to maintain the CTRL key pressed, which is impossible on a tablet.

So my question is : Is there a way to select multiple item in a ListView with a simple click on it?

Answer (score 1):

You may filter the normal mouse **Click** event and convert it to **Ctrl+Click**. Actually to **Shortcut+Click** since the shortcut key may differ on the platform the app run.

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> eventHandler = ( event ) ->
{
    if ( !event.isShortcutDown() )
    {
        Event.fireEvent( event.getTarget(), cloneMouseEvent( event ) );
        event.consume();
    }
};

listview.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode( SelectionMode.MULTIPLE );
listview.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, eventHandler );
listview.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, eventHandler );
```

where cloneMouseEvent is

```
private MouseEvent cloneMouseEvent( MouseEvent event )
{
    switch (Toolkit.getToolkit().getPlatformShortcutKey())
    {
        case SHIFT:
            return new MouseEvent(
                    event.getSource(),
                    event.getTarget(),
                    event.getEventType(),
                    event.getX(),
                    event.getY(),
                    event.getScreenX(),
                    event.getScreenY(),
                    event.getButton(),
                    event.getClickCount(),
                    true,
                    event.isControlDown(),
                    event.isAltDown(),
                    event.isMetaDown(),
                    event.isPrimaryButtonDown(),
                    event.isMiddleButtonDown(),
                    event.isSecondaryButtonDown(),
                    event.isSynthesized(),
                    event.isPopupTrigger(),
                    event.isStillSincePress(),
                    event.getPickResult()
            );

        case CONTROL:
            return new MouseEvent(
                    event.getSource(),
                    event.getTarget(),
                    event.getEventType(),
                    event.getX(),
                    event.getY(),
                    event.getScreenX(),
                    event.getScreenY(),
                    event.getButton(),
                    event.getClickCount(),
                    event.isShiftDown(),
                    true,
                    event.isAltDown(),
                    event.isMetaDown(),
                    event.isPrimaryButtonDown(),
                    event.isMiddleButtonDown(),
                    event.isSecondaryButtonDown(),
                    event.isSynthesized(),
                    event.isPopupTrigger(),
                    event.isStillSincePress(),
                    event.getPickResult()
            );

        case ALT:
            return new MouseEvent(
                    event.getSource(),
                    event.getTarget(),
                    event.getEventType(),
                    event.getX(),
                    event.getY(),
                    event.getScreenX(),
                    event.getScreenY(),
                    event.getButton(),
                    event.getClickCount(),
                    event.isShiftDown(),
                    event.isControlDown(),
                    true,
                    event.isMetaDown(),
                    event.isPrimaryButtonDown(),
                    event.isMiddleButtonDown(),
                    event.isSecondaryButtonDown(),
                    event.isSynthesized(),
                    event.isPopupTrigger(),
                    event.isStillSincePress(),
                    event.getPickResult()
            );

        case META:
            return new MouseEvent(
                    event.getSource(),
                    event.getTarget(),
                    event.getEventType(),
                    event.getX(),
                    event.getY(),
                    event.getScreenX(),
                    event.getScreenY(),
                    event.getButton(),
                    event.getClickCount(),
                    event.isShiftDown(),
                    event.isControlDown(),
                    event.isAltDown(),
                    true,
                    event.isPrimaryButtonDown(),
                    event.isMiddleButtonDown(),
                    event.isSecondaryButtonDown(),
                    event.isSynthesized(),
                    event.isPopupTrigger(),
                    event.isStillSincePress(),
                    event.getPickResult()
            );

        default: // well return itself then
            return event;

    }
}
```